# delay between two inputs java

Tags: java, input, libgdx, delay

I'm creating a little game as a project for my studies using Java with Libgdx.
The game is really simple: 2D, side view, controled with the arrowpad and everything is seen like in a grid divided in units (player is 1 unit tall, environment tides are 1 unit tall, ...).
The problem is that the movement of the character is quick (and it has to be) so it's really hard to move only 1 unit to the left or to the right.
I was wondering if it's possible to create a delay between two inputs from the keyboard because the movement part is in an "update" method so everytime I press a key it creates like 5 or 10 inputs.
I tried to handle it with java timers (like 0.2 or 0.3 sec) that happened everytime I press a key and unable the programm to listen to the keyboard until the timer is done. But I find it really dirty so i'm asking for your help to lead me on a more decent way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: When you do GUI game think game loop. Look it up it will make your life easier. http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily implement a cooldown kind of thing, by comparing the last time of use by the current time.

```
double coolDownInMillis = 1200;
double lastTime = 0;

public void move() {
    double now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(lastTime - now > coolDownInMillis  && pressingTheRightKey()){
        //do what you want
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Or something like this.

Comment: I think that would do the thing. Thank you.

Comment: @Herawo If so, mark my answer as a working solution please.